# How to get Decimal and Thousand separator of toLocaleString() method?

Tags: javascript

How to get Decimal and Thousand separator of toLocaleString() for the locale selected?

Example:

```
var number = 123456.789;
```

// German uses comma as decimal separator and period for thousands

```
console.log(number.toLocaleString('de-DE'));
123.456,789
```

// English uses period as decimal separator and comma for thousands

```
console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-GB'));
123,456.789
```

Is there any way to get locale separators?

Comment: @Amy this question is about how to get at the characters used in the current locale, and that question doesn't address that.

Answer (score 3):

Somthing like this should work (not tested):

```
let thousandsSeparator = Number(1000).toLocaleString().charAt(1)
let decimalSeparator = Number(1.1).toLocaleString().charAt(1)
```

Comment: In *spanish locales* the thousand separator doesn't appear until the number `10000`. So this would be a better hack `let thousandsSeparator = Number(10000).toLocaleString().charAt(2)`.

Answer (score 2):

you can get decimal separator and group separator from value. I can write below two function:

```js
   function getDecimalSeparator(locale) {
        const numberWithDecimalSeparator = 1.1;
        return Intl.NumberFormat(locale)
            .formatToParts(numberWithDecimalSeparator)
            .find(part => part.type === 'decimal')
            .value;
    }

function getNumberGroupSeparator(locale) {
        const numberWithDecimalSeparator = 1000.1;
        return Intl.NumberFormat(locale)
            .formatToParts(numberWithDecimalSeparator)
            .find(part => part.type === 'group')
            .value;
    }

console.log(getDecimalSeparator("en"));
console.log(getDecimalSeparator("fr"));
console.log(getNumberGroupSeparator("en"));
console.log(getNumberGroupSeparator("fr"));
```